# Error in production build: Index html generation failed

Tags: angular, build, angular12

Upgraded the **Angular 10** project to **Angular 12**. But now on running production build, it is giving error

> Index HTML generation failed.
> undefined:6:720366 missing '}'

```
ng build --configuration production --aot
```

[image]

It is very difficult to find the error because it points to the generated HTML file.
Node log will no do much.

The content of `index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Quiz - Admin</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<app></app>

</body>

</html>
```

While running the development build, locally does not give any error, even `ng build` completed successfully

Please check the build pipeline here: https://github.com/anuj9196/quiz-app/runs/2589355739?check_suite_focus=true#step:7:56

Comment: try simply `ng build`

Comment: `ng build` completed successfully

Comment: Now angular 12 we don't require to add --prod. ng build will do it automatically. And also no requirement for --aot. It's default now.

Comment: In my case, setting `"buildOptimizer": false` in `angular.json` is working fine. when `true`, it is giving the above error.

Comment: Same case, but it tells me:  Index html generation failed.
undefined:9:146288: property missing ':'. Everything worked fine until upgrading to 12.

Comment: @fmdavid Check https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20804#issuecomment-841623644 for solution

Comment: For me, it was the use of  `@media all {}` that give me an error, I just had to remove it and it worked flawlessly [this is the bug report](https://github.com/cssnano/cssnano/issues/1105)

Comment: In angular.json modify the "optimization": true to following code - 


"optimization": { "scripts": true, "fonts": { "inline": true }, "styles": { "minify": true, "inlineCritical": false } },

Here is the GitHub issues - 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20804#issuecomment-841623644

Comment: In angular.json
replace "optimization": true
to
"optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": {
                  "minify": true,
                  "inlineCritical": false
                },

Comment: I had the same problem when mocing from Angular 9 to 12 !  I tried the workarround  and it solved it   replace "optimization :"true" in production configuration ( angular.json by        : "optimization": {
"scripts": true,
"styles": {
"minify": true,
"inlineCritical": false
},
"fonts": true
}

Comment: Please read this for the correct answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67742918/angular-12-index-html-generation-failed-error

Comment: The detail for the error can be found here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20804

Comment: Check this link for a solution specific to Angular 12 https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20804#issuecomment-850937763

Comment: Had the same misterious problem. The line:column problem was related to the style.css generated. Went on that line:column and there was a typo error: inculde instead of include. In my opinion, this question should be reopened.

Comment: In Angular 12, this is your answer:    "optimization": {
                                "scripts": true,
                                "styles": {
                                  "minify": true,
                                  "inlineCritical": false
                                },
                                "fonts": false
                              },

Comment: This appears to be a known bug.  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20760

Comment: To properly debug the problem, try running `ng serve --prod`. You should be able to find the error.

Answer (score 7):

The error is not in the `index.html` file that you see in the folder structure. It occurs on generating the final index.html. This is a compilation error probably in the `css/scss` files (as the typescript seem to compile correctly). Make sure you have all curly brackets `}` closed in your css files.

Comment: `ng build` completes successfully. Also the same project was not giving any such error on Angular 10.

Comment: I am having the same issue when I upgraded the project to Angular 12. But still looking for a solution.

Comment: Had the same misterious problem. The line:column problem was related to the style.css generated. Went on that line:column and there was a typo error: inculde instead of include. In my opinion, this question should be reopened.

Comment: run `ng s --prod` to debug.