# Angular 12 Index html generation failed error

Tags: angular, angular12, angularbuild

Upgrading to angular 12 with the following command `ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12` cause me to have the following error, when compiled with the `--configuration production` mode.

```
✖ Index html generation failed.
undefined:15:4027680: missing '}'
```

*It's a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67537268/index-html-generation-failed-on-ng-build-prod-in-angular-12) but wanted to post a proper question / answer since it will surely help others and I don't know when we will be able to post again on the thread since it was closed some days ago*

Comment: In angular.json replace "optimization": true to "optimization": { "scripts": true, "styles": { "minify": true, "inlineCritical": false }

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In **angular.json** replace:

```
"optimization": true
```

to:

```
"optimization": { 
 "scripts": true, 
 "styles": { 
  "minify": true, 
  "inlineCritical": false 
 }
}
```

Comment: It seems to have worked, thx a lot!
Could you explain me what could be the impact of changing the optimization like the following ?

Comment: Looks like there is a small error on the CSS file. And the angular compiler is not ignoring them anymore

Answer (score 1):

it's an error from the cssnano library [here the bug report](https://github.com/cssnano/cssnano/issues/1105) reporter in the [following topic](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20804#issuecomment-842081228) that was included in the latest version of angular.

Basically

> Providing the following input:
> `@media all { p{ display: none; } }` 
> The following output is generated
> `@media{p{display: none;}}`

But `@media` alone doesn't exist, which result in a compiling error.

#### To find where the error is

In the message you see in the console, `undefined:15` the `15` is the line, in your **style.scss** that cause the bug to happen.

For me, I had to comment the code.

Comment: My issue was similar; I had some `@import` CSS files in my **style.css**, and that's where the main problem was. Simply commenting out the import lines solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same issue in my Angular 12 project. On my style.scss file, I was importing the Google fonts using:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700&family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,700;1,700&display=swap');
```

So I proceeded to embed them on my index.html file:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700&family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,700;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Problem solved.