Angular ng build gives error link.parentNode.insertBefore is not a function
I have an Angular v16 app that currently works fine when I serve it on my local machine.
Anyway when I try to build it, it gives me the following response:
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Copying assets complete.
✖ Index html generation failed.
link.parentNode.insertBefore is not a function

I don't use the insertBefore function in any of my components or services.
I thought it could depend from the fact I have installed jquery and datatables in my project (since I know there are some incompatibility issues between angular and jquery and I saw insertBefore is used frequently in jquery.js) but even after uninstalling all the dependencies and commenting the references, it keeps failing the ng build with the same error.
What can it be? I truly have no clue...

Please refer this Question in StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67537268/error-in-production-build-index-html-generation-failed

I think there is an issue with when Angular is trying to manipulate the DOM during the build process.

You can clear the cache and install all the dependencies again.
npm cache clean --force
rm -rf node_modules
npm install

Update Angular dependencies
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core

Checked if you're using any custom scripts or there is third-party library issues.

Also check if there's any misconfiguration in angular.json and tsconfig.json that might affect the build process.

Sometimes, index.html file can cause issues in the build process. What you can try is, create a new Angular project and copy the index.html from the new project to your existing project. And do the adjustment according to your needs.

You can also used verbose logging for more build details.
ng build --verbose


You can try all these steps. I hope you will find the solution in the process.

That was the correct direction, I simply rebuilt the app from scratch and put all the files and folders back in the new project, thanks!

You welcome .. have fun ;)

just use link?.parentNode?.insertBefore or (link?.parentNode as any)?.insertBefore

The problem is that, as I just said, I don't use that function anywhere and don't know where it's used...
Looks like it's generated inside the main.js when I build the app...

when check node version compitable

Probably it depended on that, though I can't change the version cause I'm working on a VPS

when up or down angular packages version
